# How to use Java Facelets as a general template engine in standalone application?

Tags: java, templates, facelets

I'd like to use Facelets to generate HTML contents. I want to reuse existing taglibs, which isn't supported by Velocity.

I have read the developer's guide, but didn't get a clue.

Does Facelets need a Java compiler to work? (I guess not) I've also tried with Jetty ServletTester, but it seems not work.

So is it possible?

Comment: Jetty ServletTester doesn't work well with `jsf-ri`, use `myfaces-impl` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

It's not necessary to have a Java compiler to render the view. Facelets is completely taglib-driven, only EL (expression language) may be occurred in the template script, so nothing needs to be static compiled.

To embed Facelets in a standalone application, you can programmatic initialize a servlet context. I'm using Jetty in this case. See the implementation of `ServletTester` class, and write you own server.

It's valuable to mention that `jsf-ri` doesn't work well, however, luckily we have another choice, we can use `myfaces-impl` which does better.

The main problem remains is about `ResourceResolver`. If you need to setup a complicated resource structure, i.e., the template files (xhtml) are placed in different locations, then you need to:

1. Create your own `ResourceResolver` delegates `DefaultResourceResolver`.
2. Override `org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.getResource()` to make it returns consistent resources with the `ResourceResolver`. Or similar ones if the embedded servlet context isn't Jetty-based.